# 24v dc High current variable speed Voltage regulator

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, dc-motor, dc-dc-converter, linear-regulator

I’m in need off a high current voltage regulator. I know a little about electronics, but not on an engineering level of designing stuff. I have a few stuff on scrap boards that I can use that lying around my garage.

I have 24v dc input driving motor rated at 24 V, 25 A.
I need to operate the motor at somewhere in the 12 to 24 v range in order to get the right rpm to spin a PMA (Permanent Magnet Alternator).

The parts I have on hand are :

- 10-Lm317
- 50-Lm7805
- 4-2sc5200
- 5-Tp122
- 10-d2390
- Big heat sink
- 10-10k resistors
- Uc2842N
- Uc2854
- cny17-3
- kia555p
- 8-5Watts 0.22ohm ceramic resisters
- ST UA741cn

[image]

Comment: What current does the motor require? (or what current will the regulator have to provide?)

Comment: 25 amps plus, sorry forgot about that detail

Comment: What is the “right voltage” and current? Then match the same mechanical power. You will need to regulate RPM for stability with a Tach

Comment: It has to be variable voltage regulator, aim using a charge controller and it put is 50v dc max and at 12v it only put out 28v dc after rectified and at 24v it put out 81v dc after rectified. Thats why I need a variable speed regulator to set it.

Comment: look into electric scooter and wheelchair parts.

Comment: I did, but the scooter controller Go full throttle from off to on. Wheelchair I will look into, but I want to use whatever parts I have to build a regulator.

Comment: Your accepted answer will not work (the LM31t is rated at 1 to 2 A) and if it did, you's need to dissipate say 150 Watts at 6V drop at 25A.

Comment: I’m not worried about heating, I have very large heatsinks that came from a 8kw inverter that had 150 and 200 amp igbt’s

Answer (score 1):

An "easy enough" method is to on/off PWM the supply to the motor with a variable duty cycle square wave.
.
The [**2SD2390 transistors**](http://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/2sd2390_ds_en.pdf) are Darlingtons rated at 10A each.
So use say 4 in parallel.

Apply variable duty cycle square wave drive to the bases.
You'll need a flyback diode/ diodes.
A bunch of 1N400x (1A low frequency diodes) may be the cheapest / easiest solution if you keep PWM frequency low.

At 5A Vcesat is about 1V so at 20A / 4 transistors you'll dissipate P = V x I = 1V x 20A = 20W or 5 watt per transistor.

Add your "big heatsink".
Fan cool it if necessary.

You'll need a source of variable mark space square-wave.
555 is the typical solution.
I'd use a 74xx14 (hex schmitt inverter).

**_________________________________________**

General principle:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6lONU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Darlington transistors are a very poor choice for switching use ….I'd go with the 4 * 2SC5200 (https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FJL4315-D.pdf) which would be a much better choice.

Comment: @JackCreasey I was aiming for "run what ya brung" - he says he has 10 of them to hand. | The data sheet shows they have an Ft of 20+ MHz at 5A, so at a few kHz PWM they should be very happy. (Or even at a rather higher speed).

Comment: He has 4 of the 2SC5200. But I admit the 2SD2390 look as if they could be driven with about 5mA base current. I'm not sure you are going to get viable speed control since the load current for the motor may vary. You really need a feedback mechanism to set a given rpm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Pwm hmm was looking more on the simple linear setup but what ever is best, like I said I’m not an engineer so. I have listed some extra stuff I grabbed from work when I saw the pwm suggestion. Also remember I need it to be variable speed controlled.

Comment: Is there a way to add pics in the comments

Comment: @ComputerTech A linear regulator will produce large amounts of heat. At 20A as Power = V x I you get 1 x 20 = 20 Watts per volt reduced. Reduce Vmotor by 5 volts and you have to dissipate 100 Watts of heat somewhere. It's not impossible, but it can be remarkably hard to achieve. || The PWM Vpltaeb reducer is on or off so any heat is produced by non-ideal aspects of the switch. | The variable resistor in my diagram varies the on period of the PWM whih alters the mean voltage out. A variable mark-space 555 cct would do as well
|

Comment: @ComputerTech You can access a web image using [text]_(web-url) <-remove "_". You can MAKE a web image that saves via this site by adding an image to an answer, copying the resultant image URL and then deleting the in-answer reference. [**Thusly**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3hdu.jpg) <- except I didn't delete your in answer image :-) <- I used [**Thusly**]_(http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3hdu.jpg) here (I had to add the http:// )

Answer (score -3):

Lm317 with a few high current bypass transistors
 You'll need a hefty potentiometer on the adjust pin.

Comment: At 25A? This seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: The LM317 is rated at an amp or 2. He wants 25A.

Comment: 25 amp or higher

Comment: Not particularly difficult with paralleled   transistors.